No suspend with kernel 5.15.0-119-generic on Lenovo x1 | Ubuntu 22.04
After an automatic upgrade, my Lenovo Thinkpad x1 did not suspend anymore. It resumed its active state after attempting to suspend.
I could not find the reason but after upgrading the kernel to 5.19 it works again.

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS using the GA kernel stack using 5.15, but the HWE kernel stack is now using 6.8 (not 5.19) so what are you using? and why mention 5.19?  (it was from Ubuntu 22.10 & hasn't been used since 22.10 reached EOL back in 2023).

Upgrade to kernel 5.19
sudo apt install linux-modules-5.19.0-46-generic  linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-46-generic
sudo apt install linux-headers-5.19.0-46-generic
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic

Probably one can do it in one command.

I'd have provided WARNING notices that you'll be installing an unsupported kernel by doing this, and thus won't have the benefits of security patches providing by Ubuntu, due to use of 22.10 or EOL kernel... A quick look at https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-hwe-5.19/linux-hwe-5.19_5.19.0-50.50/changelog shows patches >12 months old now.  Suitable for offline use for sure though.

It was not planned to be long-term. Just for some time. Now I should know how to switch back to the ubuntu standard kernel with automatic update. Help welcome.
